# Publicar no facebook direto - iOS9

Tags: ios, swift

Criei um código usando Swift e o SDK do Facebook para iOS9, consigo logar e fazer share, porém para fazer o share preciso clicar no botão de share que o sdk fornece, então ele abre a caixa de share padrão do facebook para fazer o share.
Preciso fazer o share de forma diferente, quando o usuário clicar no botão compartilhar no meu app eu ja envio direto para o facebook dele, sem exibir os caixa de dialogo do facebook e sem sair da minha app, mantendo a tela atual da app.
É possível fazer isso?

Comment: é possível sim vc tem que usar o SDK do facebook. mais informações em: https://developers.facebook.com

Comment: Obrigado, o link com os recursos é esse:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph#posting

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível, você precisa usar uma classe chamada `FBSDKShareDialog`.

[Referência aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKShareDialog/)